# The structure and meaning of "How far along have you gotten?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

I was wondering what the structure and meaning of "How far along have you gotten?" in the following sentences are:

> You were looking at variations in climate in the Grant City area,
>   right? **How far along have you gotten?**

I searched the dictionary, but I cannot find an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently a task has been assigned that involves the climate in a particular area.

When someone asks "How far along have you gotten?", they are imagining that the task is like a road. When the task was first assigned, that represents the beginning of the road. The completion of the task is the end of that road. As you do the work to complete the task, you are traveling along that imaginary road.

So the question means, "How far along the (imaginary) road have you traveled?" In other words, "How much work has been completed?"